# Google sheet select rows of paid where open and paid are there and open only and paid only

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with about 10000 rows . It's has invoices which are marked as paid and open. Many of them are marked as paid in one row and open on another row (same invoice number). I want to extract only the paid invoices , which also have an open entry and the open invocies which have no paid entry. Also select where paid only is there.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to construct an answer to your question. Consider the following as one approach.

**Paid invoices with an Open entry**

`=query({query({A2:C},"select Col1,Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Paid' order by Col1")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1="&JOIN(" or Col1=",query({A3:C},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Open' order by Col1"))&""&" label Col3 'Paid and Open' ")`

**Open invoices with no Paid entry**

`=query({query({A2:C},"select Col1,Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Open' order by Col1")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1<>"&JOIN(" and Col1<>",query({A3:C},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Paid' order by Col1"))&""&"")`

**Paid invoices with no Open entry**

`=query({query({A2:C},"select Col1,Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Paid' order by Col1")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1<>"&JOIN(" and Col1<>",query({A3:C},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Open' order by Col1"))&""&"")`

**Comments:**

- each answer replies on a nested queries
- the initial query includes `where` clause for the default Status value
- the `where` clause in the second query relies on a `JOIN` function to include or exclude invoices with a given Status
- the `JOIN` function uses a third query to provide the array results for the required Status.
- the `JOIN` function also includes `AND`/`OR` that operates on the `where` clause

---

### [image: snapshot]

**Credit:** @benfromredant [Using query to find the entries in one column which are not in the other](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125305/196152)

Comment: WOW!!!
Can you pl share the formula which has all 3 in a single formula.